# Why is a copy constructor being called when passing an atomic into a variadic argument?

Tags: c++, atomic, variadic-functions

I'm trying to pass a `std::atomic<unsigned int>` into a function with a variadic argument as such:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <atomic>

void info(const char* expression, ...)
{
    std::va_list arg;
    va_start(arg, expression);

    std::vprintf(expression, arg);
    std::printf("\n");
    std::fflush(stdout);

    va_end(arg);
}

int main()
{
    std::atomic<unsigned int> value(10);
    info("Testing: %u", value);

    return 0;
}
```

As is, I get the compiler error: `error: use of deleted function ‘std::atomic::atomic(const std::atomic&)’`. However, if I change the info call in main to `info("Testing: %u", value.load());`, it all works fine.

Why is the copy constructor getting called when I don't specify a load?

Comment: `info` takes it paramers by value.  Why wouldn't it make a copy?

Comment: Note: C-style variadic functions and C++ objects don't mix.

Comment: Hmm... your investigation of this issue might have been with blinders on. Did you ask yourself why the copy constructor is *not* called when you *do* specify a load (in other words, when you use `load()` to convert your `std::atomic` object to an `unsigned int`)? This might lead you to question your assumptions, such as the assumption that the use of `std:atomic` (as opposed to another type) is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy Constructors are called in 3 circumstances:

1. When an object is passed by value
2. When an object is returned by value
3. When an object is initialized to the value of an object of the same type.

If you do not want to call the copy constructor, pass the object by reference (preferably constant) to avoid calling the copy constructor.